# Deploy pre compiled bytecode using truffle migrations deployer api

Tags: truffle, bytecode, uniswap

I want to deploy pre-compiled Smart Contract bytecode using Truffle migrations. Specifically, it is the Uniswap V2 Factory contract.

In the [Uniswap V2 documentation](https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/smart-contract-integration/quick-start/) there is a cliffhanger, where they mention to use:

```js
const UniswapV2FactoryBytecode = require('@uniswap/v2-core/build/UniswapV2Factory.json').bytecode
```

And then deploy it using Truffle (but do not include an example). However, I cannot get the deployment to work. Here is my migration script:

```js
const UniswapV2FactoryBytecode = require('@uniswap/v2-core/build/UniswapV2Factory.json').bytecode
module.exports = function(_deployer, network, accounts) {
    _deployer.deploy(UniswapV2FactoryBytecode, accounts[0])
};
```

Note the `UniswapV2Factory` constructor requires a `_feeToSetter` address which is why I pass `accounts[0]` as a parameter.

When I run using `truffle migrate --reset` the following error is returned:

```
TypeError: contract.detectNetwork is not a function
```

Can anyone help point to a solution get this to work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One solution appears to be to install `@truffle/contract` package like so:

```
npm install @truffle/contract
```

Then in the migration file you will need to grab the full contract JSON (not just the bytecode as mentioned in the question) and use the `@truffle/contract` to create a contract instance from the JSON. You will also need to set the provider manually, and set the deployer account manually too.

```js
const json = require('@uniswap/v2-core/build/UniswapV2Factory.json')
const contract = require('@truffle/contract');
const UniswapV2Factory = contract(json);

UniswapV2Factory.setProvider(this.web3._provider);

module.exports = function(_deployer, network, accounts) {
    _deployer.deploy(UniswapV2Factory, accounts[0], {from: accounts[0]})
};
```

Given all the extra hoops to jump through this might not be the best approach but it does produce what I was after - an instance of the contract deployed in my development environment.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was copying the `UniswapV2Factory`  contract's JSON file into `build/contracts` folder. Then I just used it as any other artifact with `artifacts.require("UniswapV2Factory");`.